# How to disable a modal from triggering on phones and tablets only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

```js
$(function() {
  $('.pop').on('click', function() {
    $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    $('#imagemodal').modal('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.modal-backdrop.in {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#imagemodal .modal-dialog {
  width: 70%;
  position: center;
}
@media (max-width: 987px) {
  .pop:hover {
    opacity: 100;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    /* For IE8 and earlier */
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#" class="pop">
      <img src="images/powwow/powwow_01.jpg" style="width: 100%">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <img src="" class="imagepreview" style="width: 100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a model that I want to disable for phones and tablets, but want to keep for larger screens. I've tried `visibility:hidden` and `display:none` in CSS media queries, but get strange results. I think I need to disable the onClick function but can't figure out how to do that for just smaller screens.

Comment: Have a look at my answer. it also has a working code snippet. should do what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Javascript to show the model, simply check if the device fits your criteria before actually showing it. I've written a custom function based on another SO post to check if device is mobile. Then you could also check if the screen width is allowable.

Replace your Javascript with this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.pop').on('click', function() {
      $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
      if($( window ).width()<800 || isMobile()){
         //do substitute operation for mobile screens
      } else {
         $('#imagemodal').modal('show');
      }   
    });   
});
function isMobile() {
  var isMobile = false; //initiate as false
  // device detection
  if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0, 4))) isMobile = true;
  return isMobile;
}
```

FULL WORKING CODE:

The modal won't show if it is a mobile device or if screen size is less than 800pixels. Tweak to your settings as needed. Click `run code snippet` to see it in action!

```js
$(function() {
  $('.pop').on('click', function() {
    $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    if ($(window).width() < 800 || isMobile()) {
      //do substitute operation for mobile screens and delete below 3 lines
      console.log("model not showed!!");
      console.log("isMObile : " + isMobile());
      console.log("screen size :" + $(window).width() + "px  min is 800px");
    } else {
      $('#imagemodal').modal('show');
    }
  });
});

function isMobile() {
  var isMobile = false; //initiate as false
  // device detection
  if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0, 4))) isMobile = true;
  return isMobile;
}
```

```css
.modal-backdrop.in {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#imagemodal .modal-dialog {
  width: 70%;
  position: center;
}
@media (max-width: 987px) {
  .pop:hover {
    opacity: 100;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    /* For IE8 and earlier */
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#" class="pop">
      <img src="images/powwow/powwow_01.jpg" style="width: 100%">click
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <img src="" class="imagepreview" style="width: 100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks to L.Dia for mentioning screen size check also. I have added the check.

Comment: Thanks Iceman! Your solution works perfectly - just as I was envisioning. I wish I could download your brain! Thanks again.

Comment: Cheers. Happy it helped.

Comment: @StickupArtist could you accept the answer. (the small tick on the left of the answer);

Comment: @StickupArtist http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

With Iceman's reply 
You can also unbind the click from your button depending on the width or if it's a tablet/mobile :

```
if( isMobile() || (screen.width <= 800)) {
            $(#yourbutton).unbind('click');
        }
```

Use css to change the appearence of the button depending on the width, users won't be tempted to click.

Answer (score 0):

I a assuming that you are using Bootstrap. If so, you can use native hide classes of bootstrap like **hidden-xs** etc. Or, you can just use visibility classes like **visible-lg**; Since Bootstrap is a mobile first framework, your modal won't show up other that large screen devices. For your scenario this is working fine.

```
<div class="modal fade visible-lg" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  ...
</div>
```

If you are still insisting on a JavaScript solution, still assuming that you are using Bootstrap, so you are using jQuery, this will get the window width and allow you you to control the event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var $window = $(window);

            function checkWidth() {
                var windowsize = $window.width();
                if (windowsize < 1200) {
                    $(".pop").click(function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });
                }

                else {
                    $(function () {
                        $('.pop').on('click', function () {
                            $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
                            $('#imagemodal').modal('show');
                        });
                    });
                }
            }

            checkWidth();
            $(window).resize(checkWidth);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Cromwell. I implemented your code, but the scroll was disabled for the smaller screens. But then, it is very possible I entered it in incorrectly. Thank you!